# HQL: How to query certain fields when one of those fields is a one-to-many List?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am having difficulty writing a HQL query to select ONLY the `caseid`, `title`, and `caseStatus` fields from my `Cases` entity. The cases returned have to be distinct based on caseid. I do not want the `name` and `userid` fields to be included. I also do not want to use Lazy fetching for `caseid`, `title`, and `caseStatus` fields. Note that the `caseStatus` field is a one-to-many List. Below are the entities. The getters/setters are omitted to save space.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cases")
public class Cases {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "caseid", nullable = false)
    private Integer caseid;
    private Integer userid;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    @OrderBy("caseStatusId DESC")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cases", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CaseStatus> caseStatus;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CaseStatus")
public class CaseStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "caseStatusId", nullable = false)
    private Integer caseStatusId;
    private String info;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "caseid")
    private Cases cases;
}
```

My goal is to retrieve a distinct `List<Cases>` or `List<Object[]>` of the Cases entity containing only `caseid`, `title`, and a `List<CaseStatus>`. The `List<CaseStatus>` will contain `CaseStatus` objects with all of its fields populated.

```
public List<Object[]> getCases(String title) {
    TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery("select distinct c.caseid, c.title, cs "
        + "FROM Cases c join c.caseStatus cs "
        + "where c.title like :title", Object[].class);
    q.setParameter("title", "%" + title + "%");
    List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

The above method is close, but not correct because rather than returning a `List<CaseStatus>` in one of the indexes, it is only returning a single `CaseStatus` entity.

For example, if my DB contains a single `Case` with a `List<CaseStatus>` having a size of n for example, the results will be similar to the example below:

Example of results I'm getting now. Not correct:

```
        List<Object[]> index 0:
            Contains an Object[] where:
                Object[0] = {some caseid}
                Object[1] = {some title}
                Object[2] = {1st CaseStatus}
        List<Object[]> index 1:
            Contains an Object[] where:
                Object[0] = {same caseid as the one found in index 0 above}
                Object[1] = {same title as the one found in index 0 above}
                Object[2] = {2nd CaseStatus}
        ...
        List<Object[]> index n-1:
            Contains an Object[] where:
                Object[0] = {same caseid as all the previous}
                Object[1] = {same title as all the previous}
                Object[2] = {nth CaseStatus}
```

Example of results I hope to achieve:

```
        List<Object[]> index 0:
            Contains an Object[] where:
                Object[0] = {unique caseid}
                Object[1] = {some title}
                Object[2] = List<CaseStatus> with size of n
```

Updated the question. Instead of `name`, `title`, and `List<CaseStatus>`, the fields I want to retrieve are `caseid`, `title`, and `List<CaseStatus>`. `caseid` is the primary key of Cases.

I found various threads [Select Collections with HQL - hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=991742) and [Select collections with HQL - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491812/select-collections-with-hql). It's pretty much the problem I ran into. Looks like no one found a solution in these threads.

Comment: Can you post generated SQL query?

Comment: Looking at the error message, It says "Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'." , I don't see any "as" keyword in your query, Did you post the right query?

Comment: It's HQL, the hibernate generated queries are where you'll find the offending "as". You can see this if you set org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL (or 'hibernate.show_sql') to true in your hibernate configuration and set logging to debug.

Comment: Added the generated SQL query from the logging to the original post. I noticed the . as col_2_0 might be causing the error. I wonder why the HQL I wrote resulted in that.

Comment: @khiraide - See my answer below, tested on my box.

Comment: If you are asking about `HQL` why do you use `JPA`? `HQL` has nothing to do with `JPA`, so please remove `JPA` from your tag list. If you really meant `JPA` query, it is illegal to use collection valued attributes in the `select` list.

Comment: Updated the question. Instead of name, title, and List<CaseStatus>, the fields I want to retrieve are caseid, title, and List<CaseStatus>. caseid is the primary key of Cases. @fg78nc had an answer that was closest to what I want to achieve so far. I wrote an example scenario which hopefully showcases my goal.

Comment: JPA, Hibernate, JPQL or HQL -> the whole purpose of this technology stack is to work with the data in object-oriented way, not in relational way as you would do in traditional SQL syntax. This means that rather than retrieving fields, you shall retrieve entities with their associations (with other entities or embedded objects) or attributes of entities. Can we say that you want to retrieve attributes "caseid", "title" of entity "Case" and "CaseStatus" entities, associated with particular "Case"?

Comment: @fg78nc That's correct. I want to retrieve attributes "caseid", "title" of entity "Case" and "CaseStatus" entities, associated with particular "Case". Only those attributes and nothing else from Case.

Comment: Query suggested before in my answer does exactly that, provided correct association on both sides of the relationship of Case and CaseStatus.
`CaseStatus c1 = new CaseStatus();
  c1.setInfo("Hello1");
  
  CaseStatus c2 = new CaseStatus();
  c2.setInfo("Hello2");
  
  Cases case1 = new Cases();
  Cases case2 = new Cases();
  c1.setCases(case1);
  c2.setCases(case2);
  
  case1.setName("A");
  case1.setTitle("B");
  case2.setName("A2");
  case2.setTitle("B2");
  case1.getCaseStatus().add(c1);
  case2.getCaseStatus().add(c2);
  
  em.persist(case1);
  em.persist(case2);`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernates a bit confused about the query; in HQL do your join like this (apologies, I've not been able to test before posting due to wonky computer, but you should get the idea)

```
select distinct c from Cases c left join fetch c.caseStatus cs where....
```

the "fetch" makes it eager. Note that this will return an array of type Cases. You where clauses look about right.

Answer (score 0):

In fact HQL is fully object-oriented and uses your classes structure in the Query, so by writing `c.caseStatus` HQL expects that your `Cases` class has a `caseStatus` property, which is wrong because it's a collection.

If you take a look at [Hibernate **HQL** documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) you can see that:

> Compared with SQL, however, HQL **is fully object-oriented** and understands notions like inheritance, polymorphism and association.

I think what you need to do here is to change your query so it matches your classes structures:

```
    Query q = em.createQuery("select distinct c.name, c.title, cs.caseStatus FROM Cases c left join c.caseStatus where "
        + "c.name like :name and "
        + "c.title like :title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax should be

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery("select c.name, c.title, cs FROM Cases c "
                + "join c.caseStatus cs where "
                + "c.name = :name and "
                + "c.title = :title", Object[].class);
```

Return type will be `List<Object[]>`, where in first index of `Object[]` is c.name, second is c.title and third is associated caseStatus entity. It is possible to query for multiple instances (rows).

We need JOIN because relationship between CaseStatus and Case is mapped via collection.

```
SELECT cs
FROM Case c JOIN c.cases cs;
```

Comment: I noticed that within the result List<Object[]>, each index contains a single CaseStatus rather than a List of CaseStatus. Any way to retrieve each Case with their associated List of CaseStatus?

Comment: Also, if a Case has a List<CaseStatus> with a size greater than 2, the return List<Object[]> does not contain distinct entities based on caseid. There will be duplicate entities within it. Do you know of a way to retrieve distinct entities? I tried adding the keyword distinct to your example query, but it did not seem to affect anything.

Comment: Example: Return type will be List<Object[]>, where in first index of Object[] is c.name, second is c.title and third is associated List<CaseStatus>.

Comment: Everything depends how do you persist objects in first place. Remember that you always have to keep association both sides of relationship.  You asked : "I noticed that within the result List<Object[]>, each index contains a single CaseStatus rather than a List of CaseStatus."  The answer is: everything depends how objects are associated (linked via foreign keys) with each other.

Comment: Q : Do you know of a way to retrieve distinct entities? A: Please describe scenario , what exactly has to retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select distinct c from Cases c where "
            + "c.name like :name and "
            + "c.title like :title");
```

Just try this. This may be a naive approach but should be able to solve the problem. You may be getting more fields than you required but the return type would be list of Cases.